# Calculation of the mean of array data points lying under a predefined rectangle

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data points in an array, and a predefined `rectangle` lying within the area of my array. My goal is to calculate the `Mean` of my array points lying under the area of the rectangle. But I have one problem, the coordinates of the rectangle in my array are determined from the bottom left corner, BUT the coordinates in my `table` function are determined from the upper left corner. Which means that I will always take different values than the rectangle are overlapping. Has someone an idea how to fix this?

```
TestDataPoints = RandomInteger[10, {6, 6}]
TestDataPointsGraph = 
   ArrayPlot[TestDataPoints , 
     PlotRange -> All,
     ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
     ImageSize -> Small,
     Frame -> False]

TestQuader = Rectangle[{1, 1}, {3, 3}]
TestQuaderGraphic = Graphics[{Green, TestQuader}]

HighlightImage[TestDataPointsGraph, TestQuaderGraphic]

AreaDetermination =
  Table[
    TestDataPoints[[RowData]][[ColumnData]], 
    {RowData, 3, 1}, {ColumnData, 1, 3}]
N[Mean[Flatten[AreaDetermination]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you asking. Especially, I do not understand why you introducing image processing into you work. Just to find the mean of a subarray requires no resort images and image processing. So I suggest the following. If it doesn't work for you, I ask you to explain -- by updating your question, not by commenting on this answer -- why this isn't what you want.

```
SeedRandom[42]; pts = RandomInteger[10, {6, 6}];
pts // MatrixForm
```

[image: pts]

```
rect = pts[[4 ;; 6]][[All, 1 ;; 3]];
rect // MatrixForm
```

[image: rect]

```
N[Mean[Flatten[rect]]]
```

> `5.77778`

Comment: Thank you a lot, that is an easier way! I guess for you the next questions is an easy task, but how can I now mark the rect data e.g. with a frame in my arrayplot?

Comment: Why not use `pts[[4 ;; 6, 1 ;; 3]]`?